# What are the appropriate argument/return types for a function to take binary files/streams/filenames and convert them to readable text format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that's intended to take a binary file format and convert it to a readable text format, e.g.:

```
def textualize(binary_stuff):
    # magic to turn binary stuff into text
    return text_stuff
```

There are a few different types I could accept as input or produce as output, and I'm unsure what to use. Here are some options and corresponding objections I can think of:

1. Take a bytes object as input and return a string.

   - Problematic if, say, the input is originating from a huge file that now has to be read into memory.
2. Take a file-like object as input, read it, and return a string.

   - Relies on the caller to open the file in the right mode.
   - The asymmetry of this disturbs me for reasons I can't quite put a finger on.
3. Take two file-like objects; read from one and write to the other instead of returning anything.

   - Again relies on the caller to open the files in the right mode.
   - Makes the most common cases (named file to named file, or bytes to string) more unwieldly than they need to be.
4. Take two filenames and handle opening stuff myself.

   - What if the caller wants to convert data that isn't in a named file?
5. Accept multiple possible input types.

   - Possibly complicated to program.
   - Still leaves the question of what to return.

Is there an established Right Thing to do for conversions like this? Are there additional tradeoffs I'm missing?

Comment: More abstraction is usually better.  Just generic streams.

Comment: I like this question a lot but please firm up the specificity on what we are supposed to "return"? You could return a file object, a string/bytes object, an iterator (yielding lines), or do option 3 (read from input, write to output). The "right" answer depends on how much processing the read will do; are we seeking, pattern-matching, summarizing, extracting keywords or feature vectors... please tell us your **main use case(s)? Generality is admirable, but beware of overdoing it and [becoming an architecture astronaut, as Joel warns](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this how the `json` module does this. One function for strings and another for files. And leave the opening and closing of files to the caller -- gives the caller more flexibility. You could then use `functools.singledispatch` to provide ways to dispatch your functions

eg.

```
from functools import singledispatch
from io import BytesIO, StringIO, IOBase, TextIOBase

@singledispatch
def textualise(input, output):
    if not isinstance(input, IOBase):
        raise TypeError(input)
    if not isinstance(output, TextIOBase):
        raise TypeError(output)
    data = input.read().decode("utf-8")
    output.write(data)
    output.flush()

@textualise.register(bytes)
def textualise_bytes(bytes_):
    input = BytesIO(bytes_)
    output = StringIO()
    textualise(input, output)
    return output.getvalue()

@textualise.register(str)
def textualise_filenames(in_filename, out_filename):
    with open(in_filename, "rb") as input, open(out_filename, "wt") as output:
        textualise(input, output)

s = textualise(b"some text")
assert s == "some text"

textualise("inputfile.txt", "outputfile.txt")
```

I would personally avoid the the third form since `bytes` objects are also valid filenames. For example, `textualise(b"inputfile.txt", "outputfile.txt")` would get dispatched to the wrong function (`textualise_bytes`).

Comment: This looks like a promising approach to me. Makes me a bit nervous that I can't find singledispatch in the documentation, though -- even though I can see it's there in dir(functools), and it's described in PEP 443.

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the right documentation. Singledispatch is new in 3.4 and so won't appear in documentation before that - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html . You can also look at documentation by using the `help` function on a method or module eg. `help(functools.singledispatch)`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it seems Google was pointing me to the 3.3 docs. I see it now. Thanks.